# Use pivot-tables with different models

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I got the following models:

- User
- UserGroup
- Item

Now every user has a `belongsToMany` relation to `Item` with pivot:

```
    public function items()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Item::class)
            ->withPivot('value');
    }
```

This is the structure of `item`:

`Item`

- title

  - pivot:

    - value

**Example**

`User`

- name: Tim
- items:

  - title: car
  - value (pivot): 2

Now it's getting tricky: I'd like to use `User` also in the model `UserGroup` - and each `User` should have many `Item`s with  a **new** pivot table, that's not identical to the pivot table, the `Item` has, when it's a pivot of `User`.

**Example**

`UserGroup`

- name: Party-Group
- users:

  - name: Tim
  - items:

    - title: car
    - value (pivot): 3

### My approach

So I think, the only possible solution would be to create something like a new model called `UserGroupUser` (extended from `User`) with a relation to `UserGroupUserItems` (extended from `Item`).

But maybe there's a smarter way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a users() method on the User group like so:

```php
class UserGroup extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
}

// Then to retrieve your data:
$groups = UserGroup::with('users.items')->get();
dd($groups);
```